# Vercel Deployment Stuck on queue

Tags: next.js, queue, vercel

Why is my deployment on Vercel stuck in the queue, and what can I do about it?

[image]
Your deployment may be stuck in the queue due to a delay in build processing for Hobby users, as Vercel is investigating an issue affecting build queue processing times. This doesn't affect existing deployments or live traffic. While this is being resolved, you can:

[image]

Wait for a resolution: Vercel will update their status page as they investigate and resolve the issue.
Subscribe for Updates: Use the 'Subscribe To Updates' feature on Vercel's status page to receive notifications.
Upgrade Your Plan: If your work is time-sensitive, consider upgrading from the Hobby plan to a paid plan for prioritized build processing.
Check for Workarounds: Sometimes, the community may suggest temporary workarounds on forums or in discussion groups.
Contact Support: Reach out to Vercel support for more personalized assistance or to report your specific issue.